# expressionengine search {auto_path} wrong entry

Tags: search, hyperlink, expressionengine

I'm having trouble configuring the search results, linking to that specific result.

I've set the channel search preferences so that {auto_path} links to the relevant template group and template and I have had no trouble with this whatsoever.

The only trouble I am having is that when you click on the title of the result, when you are sent to the page that displays the specific entry, rather than display that specific entry, it shows you the most recent entry posted on that channel.

I’ve also noticed that when you click the result, the url which should display as this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/ee_site/index.php?/template_group/template/entry

actually renders as this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/ee_site/index.php?/template_group/template/?/entry

Whats up with the extra ‘?/’ inbetween the template and the entry?

Here is the code for the results page:

```
{embed="embeds/html-head" page_title="Blog"}

<body>

<div id="container">  

{embed="embeds/header"}

{embed="embeds/navigation"}

    <div id="hero">

         <div id="heading">

             <div id="title">
                 <h2>{exp:search:total_results} RESULT(S) FOR {exp:search:keywords}</h2>
             </div>

          </div>  

        <div id="blog">

  <ul>

{exp:search:search_results}

             <div class="blog">
                 <li class="search_results"><strong><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></strong> from <em>{channel}</em>
             <br/>
             {excerpt}
             <br/>
             </li>
             </div>

{/exp:search:search_results}

  </ul>

            </div>            

        </div>

{embed="embeds/footer"}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code for a gallery entry

```
{embed="embeds/html-head"}

<body>

<div id="container">  

{embed="embeds/header"}

{embed="embeds/navigation"}

     <div id="hero">

         <div id="heading">

{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" limit="1" disable="pagination"}          

            <div id="title">
                <h2>Gallery</h2>
            </div>

            <div id="story_title">
                <h2>{title}</h2>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div id="video_main">
                <img class="image" src="{image}" alt="{title}">
            </div>

            <div id="featured" class="main">
            <p>{info}</p>
            <p class="url">{source}</p>
            </div>

{/exp:channel:entries}

{embed="embeds/footer"}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On a category page, when you click an entry and are taken to this page, it displays the specific entry clicked on, so I know that there is nothing wrong with that aspect.

Any suggestions/solutions would be much appreciated, i'm sure it's something minor that i'm just not spotting!